# Python installation Service pack for windows

Tags: python

Python installation : 
to install python windows 7 service pack 1 and all applicable updates are required. 
Kindly tell what should be done next.

Answer (score 0):

Do what it says. Obtain Windows 7 Service Pack 1 from Microsoft (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15090/windows-7-install-service-pack-1-sp1) and install it. Otherwise (according to http://bugs.python.org/issue26056) you will have to stay on Python 3.4.